# Manually banning nodes through CLI

Tags: bitcoind, bitcoin-core, bitcoin-cli

I cant find this info: How can I ban through CLI a peer connected to my full node?

I like how can I do it in the 0.12.0 GUI just with right-click and choosing for how much time I want to ban the peer.

tia

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As correctly answered here https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=1390192.msg14122567#msg14122567

```
setban "ip(/netmask)" "add|remove" (bantime) (absolute)

Attempts add or remove a IP/Subnet from the banned list.

Arguments:
1. "ip(/netmask)" (string, required) The IP/Subnet (see getpeerinfo for nodes ip) with a optional netmask (default is /32 = single ip)
2. "command"      (string, required) 'add' to add a IP/Subnet to the list, 'remove' to remove a IP/Subnet from the list
3. "bantime"      (numeric, optional) time in seconds how long (or until when if [absolute] is set) the ip is banned (0 or empty means using the default time of 24h which can also be overwritten by the -bantime startup argument)
4. "absolute"     (boolean, optional) If set, the bantime must be a absolute timestamp in seconds since epoch (Jan 1 1970 GMT)

Examples:
> bitcoin-cli setban "192.168.0.6" "add" 86400
> bitcoin-cli setban "192.168.0.0/24" "add"
> curl --user myusername --data-binary '{"jsonrpc": "1.0", "id":"curltest", "method": "setban", "params": ["192.168.0.6", "add" 86400] }' -H 'content-type: text/plain;' http://127.0.0.1:8332/
```